# what's the meanof "The whole is greater than any of its parts"

Tags: analysis

> One interesting feature about the natural numbers is that while each individual natural number is finite, the set of natural numbers is infinite; i.e., $\mathbb N$ is infinite but consists of individually finite elements. (The whole is greater than any of its parts.)

I'm confused about "The whole is greater than any of its parts". Does the 'whole' mean the set $\mathbb N$ while the 'part' means the element in $\mathbb N$? How could a set be greater than its element?   Thank you!

Comment: It's always hard to guess what an author meant in some stray comment taken out of context.  Here, I suppose that all that's meant is that, while each natural number is (of course) finite, $\mathbb N$ is infinite.

Comment: This is equivalent to the obvious fact that there is no largest natural number. Whenever $n$ is a natural number , $n+1$ is a natural number even larger. Of course from some point on the number get too large to be reasonally describable , but in principle every natural number could be written down.

Comment: I agree. maybe the whole means the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ ?  so given any natural number n, there is n+1 greater than n. @Peter

Comment: @AndrewLi $n+1$ does have a greater cardinality than $n$, but what is meant by the statement is that $\mathbb{N}$ ("the whole") has a cardinality greater than any of its elements ("parts"). We can intuitively say that the size of $\mathbb{N}$ is infinity (precisely, its $\aleph_{0}$), yet any element only has a finite cardinality.

Comment: It's just vague poetic language that means that the aggregate has a property that the individual components do not. It isn't a technical statement because it's imprecise.